# how to assign the formula on cell depending on the value of the differnt sheet in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying write a VBA script for the summary report
I have multiple sheets
in the first sheet I have summary report
below calculations I need to do in loop for multiple sheets

```
Sheets("Dashboard").Select
Range("D5").Select
Selection.Formula = "=COUNTIF(Sheet2!E:E,""Passed"")"
```

Like above I have multiple formulas to apply on cell and I don't want to write the formula for each sheet Any suggestions plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you loop thru all the worksheets in a workbook: (avoid using `Select`)

```
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> "NameOfSheet" Then
      sh.Range("D5").Formula = "=COUNTIF('" & sh.Name & "'!E:E,""Passed"")"
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: Actually I need to add loop in formula sheet value  "=COUNTIF(Sheet2!E:E,""Passed"")"
e.g.  Sheets("Dashboard").Select
Range("D5").Select
Selection.Formula = "=COUNTIF(Sheet2!E:E,""Passed"")" Sheets("Dashboard").Select
Range("D5").Select
Selection.Formula = "=COUNTIF(Sheet3!E:E,""Passed"")"

Comment: Updated to use sheet name as variable.

Comment: There is rarely any need to use `ActiveWorkbook`, and it can have a disastrous impact in code like this. I would strongly suggest using `ThisWorkbook` in future or directly referring to a specific workbook.

Comment: This will fail if the sheet name has spaces in it. You need `"=COUNTIF('" & sh.Name & "'!E:E,""Passed"")"`

Comment: I need to update in first sheet so need to exclude that sheet from the formula :  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim row As Integer
  row = 15
  For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      Dashboard.Range("D" & row).Formula = "=COUNTIF('" & sh.Name & "'!E:E,""Passed"")"
      row = row + 1
  Next

Comment: Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim row As Integer
  row = 15
  For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
    If sh.Name <> "NameOfSheet" Then
      Dashboard.Range("D" & row).Formula = "=COUNTIF('" & sh.Name & "'!E:E,""Passed"")"
    End If
    row = row + 1
  Next
'
End Sub ---- This is throwing an error as " Run Time Error 424 Object required"

Comment: Updated the code to ignore a particular sheet name.

Comment: Yes updated , still the same error                                                         Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim row As Integer
  row = 15
  For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
    If sh.Name <> "Dashboard" Then
      Dashboard.Range("D" & row).Formula = "=COUNTIF('" & sh.Name & "'!E:E,""Passed"")"
                
    End If
    row = row + 1
  Next
'
End Sub